# Skip lines while file scanning multiple lines

Tags: c, file, line, skip, fault

This code will read a file and print it as long as the file is in this format

```
word,12,34
words,40,20
another,20,11
```

How do I get it to do the same if its got an empty line in between like this because right now it just gives me a segmentation fault

```
word,12,34

words,40,20

another,20,11



#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    FILE *pdata;
    char buffer[1000];
    char *token, *del=",";
    int value1;
    double value2;


    pdata = fopen ("file.data", "r");

    if(pdata == NULL)
    {
        printf("unable to open file \n");
        exit(1);
    }

    while( fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), pdata) != NULL )
    {
        token = strtok(buffer, del);
        value1 = atoi( strtok(NULL, del) );
        value2 = atof( strtok(NULL, del) );

        printf("%s is %.3lf\n", token, value1 + value2);

    }

    fclose( pdata );


return 0;
}
```

Please Help

Comment: Test whether `token` is NULL? and if it is, don't perform the `atoi` conversions on the next two lines (`if (token!=NULL) { value1 = ...` I think that should do the trick.

Comment: how and where do i do that?

Comment: see updated answer. Testing for NULL after every `strtok` solved it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two changes I would make:

```
char *del = ", "; // test for either space or comma
```

And (per my comment to the question earlier):

```
while( fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), pdata) != NULL )
{
    char *temp;
    token = strtok(buffer, del);
    if (token != NULL) {
      temp = strtok(NULL, del);
      if (temp) value1 = atoi( temp );
      temp = strtok(NULL, del);
      if (temp) {
        value2 = atof( temp );
        printf("%s is %.3lf\n", token, value1 + value2);
      }
}
```

The `strtok` will return NULL if no token is found. Passing a NULL string to `atoi` is what's giving you the seg fault, I'm guessing. Like this, we make absolutely sure that doesn't happen. I tested this and it works.

Comment: still getting segmentation

Comment: See my latest edits. I assign the result of each `strtok` to a `temp` variable and test it before performing `atoi` of `atof`.

Comment: i tried this still getting segmentation fault and my values are not adding correctly this is weird

Comment: lol tried that last code and it skips a line but it prints crazy for example it printed word is 34 is 34 words is 20 is 20 lol

Comment: typo when I transcribed... Using two computers - the one with C compiler is not currently online so I tested on one and re-typed code on the other. You need `atoi(temp)` not `atoi(strtok)`. Argggh.

Comment: you got it but why does it print the is at the end for example its printing word is 46 is 46 words is 60 is 60

Comment: Beats me - using exactly the code shown above? You get `word is 46 is 46` instead of `word is 46`? Try printing out the individual values? It makes no sense... Are you sure you have `double value2` and didn't change it to `int` when no-one was looking? Because strange things may happen when you pass the wrong size of parameter to `printf`. And you are not seeing (as you should with your format specifier `%.3lf`) `word is 46.000`

Comment: yeah double value2 is still the same and i even changed the print out statement to "token is %s", token; and it prints out token is word token is and so on

Comment: you had it correct i had moved the print statement out of the last if and caused the issue

Comment: i wish i had you as my tutor theres more to this code that i have to add to finish it and i have no idea how

Comment: If you have another question, post it on the forum and add a link in a comment here so I can see it. No promises that I will have time to look at it...

Answer (score 0):

```
while( fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), pdata) != NULL )
{
    if (buffer[0] == '\n') {
        /* empty line */
        continue;
    }
    token = strtok(buffer, del);
    value1 = atoi( strtok(NULL, del) );
    value2 = atof( strtok(NULL, del) );

    printf("%s is %.3lf\n", token, value1 + value2);

}
```

Comment: still get the segmentation fault

Comment: Are your empty lines just a newline, or do they have spaces in them?